# How to use "has_child" in the Rest High Level Client of ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I want to issue the following search query in ElasticSearch.

```
GET /example1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": {
      "type": "schedule",
      "query": {
        "bool": {}
      },
      "inner_hits": {},
      "max_children": 10,
      "min_children": 1,
      "score_mode": "min"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I write the above query in the Rest High Level Client in Java?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HasChildQueryBuilder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/plugin/parent-join-client/7.14.1/org/elasticsearch/join/query/HasChildQueryBuilder.html).

Official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/query-dsl-has-child-query.html).